# getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. exception

Tags: c#

Server stack trace:

> at
>   Tavisca.TravelNxt.Hotel.Core.Controllers.HotelSuppliersController.b__33(PassengerTypeQuantity
>   passengerInfo)
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2
>   predicate)

code:

```
if (passengers == null || passengers.Count == 0)
{
    _serviceStatus.MissingItems.Add(Utility.GetXmlElementORAttributeName(type, property));
    return false;
}
if (passengers.Any(passengerInfo => passengerInfo.Quantity == 0))
{
    _serviceStatus.InvalidItems.Add(Utility.GetXmlElementORAttributeName(type, property));
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Actually i want to sure that anything in passengers due to that i am getting error

Comment: I am getting error at linq

Comment: Are any of your passenger objects `null` in your list?

Comment: none of passenger objects is null

Comment: @PravinBakare +1 pravin bhau

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S.: bhau pan +1 ka?apli mati apli maanas?

Comment: @preetam lol ...yet nahis re aaj kal Online

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S.: kay tumhalach athavat yet nahi...kaditari ping kara..

Comment: @preetam hahaha...aare notice period war hoto...tyamule kamacha load khup hota...pan yet ja na aata

Answer (score 4):

Please try this

```
        if (passengers == null || (passengers != null && passengers.Count == 0))
        {
            _serviceStatus.MissingItems.Add(Utility.GetXmlElementORAttributeName(type, property));
            return false;
        }

        if (passengers.Any(passengerInfo => (passengerInfo == null) || (passengerInfo != null && passengerInfo.Quantity == 0)))
        {
            _serviceStatus.InvalidItems.Add(Utility.GetXmlElementORAttributeName(type, property));
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as @David Arno posted?

Answer (score 2):

Since the error is in linq, this means the problems is occurring on the line

```
if (passengers.Any(passengerInfo => passengerInfo.Quantity == 0))
```

and it is because one or more of the elements in `passengers` is null, thus the `passengerInfo.Quantity` part results in the object not set to an instance exception.

Try changing the line to the following to see if it resolves the error:

```
if (passengers.Any(passengerInfo => passengerInfo == null || passengerInfo.Quantity == 0))
```

(though of course, this change might in reality be masking the real problem of you having a null passengerInfo object)

Comment: he is says,none of `passengerInfo ` is `null`.

Comment: @preetam I'd suggest he's mistaken in that claim (or the problem lies outside of the code provided)

Comment: sounds correct...we cant guess anything without knowing where the problem lies?

Answer (score 1):

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` means that you have an object that is `null`, hence it's not instantiated. You solve this by ensuring that the object is in-fact instantiated.

There are multiple ways to go by this, it all depends on what you want your application to do in a case of unexpected behavior (a `null`!).

**Example of a null object**

If you were to write the following:

```
Person filip = null;
Console.WriteLine(filip.Name);
```

Then the second line would give us a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception, because we in fact now know that `filip` is `null`.

So how do we solve this?

Either we can check if it is `null` before we print it:

```
Person filip = null;
if(filip != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(filip.Name);
}
```

Or if we are getting the `Person` from another metod, we can use `??` to ensure that it is not null and if it is, we just create a new one like this:

`Person filip = GetFilip() ?? new Person();`

It all depends on what you want to do in case of a null in your application.

As others have mentioned, you need to set a breakpoint and find *where* the error are occuring, when you find that, look for what object is null and make sure that it is handled properly.

You have good information in your stack trace that leads us to the LINQ statement.

In your case, you check `if (passengers == null || passengers.Count == 0)` but at the next line you have `if (passengers.Any....)` this means that even if `passengers` is null, it will still try to `Any()` on it which will throw an exception.

Maybe you are just looking for an `else if`?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to make check for all.

```
if (passengers == null || (passengers != null && passengers.Count == 0))
{
     _serviceStatus.MissingItems.Add(Utility.GetXmlElementORAttributeName(type, property));
     return false;
}

if (passengers.Any(passengerInfo => (passengerInfo == null) || (passengerInfo != null && passengerInfo.Quantity == 0)))
{
    _serviceStatus.InvalidItems.Add(Utility.GetXmlElementORAttributeName(type, property));
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This solution is exactly what suggested by me. You should mark my suggested solution as "Answer".